# Change language on the fly in Android app writen in Xamarin with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, internationalization, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin.Android project with MvvmCross 6.1.2 and Resx resources in .NET Standard library (*Core project*).

**tl;dr:** I'd like to change language in app settings without restarting the app. Current approach requires restarting the app or causes the app crash due to high memory usage after several *switches*.

### How it's been

Till now I've been using custom `AppLanguageService` that was changing the language via `CultureInfo`.

```cs
private void ChangeLocally(string code)
{
    Settings.ApplicationLanguage = code;
    Strings.Culture = new CultureInfo(code);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Strings.Culture;
    ((MvxResxTextProvider) textProvider).CurrentLanguage = Strings.Culture;
}
```

In my Android layouts I was using `MvxLang` binding to show translated terms. In order to change language on Android I was also calling `Recreate()` in my `BaseActivity`. This, however, was causing some kind of performance issues. After couple of such language switches the app was unusably slow and crashed due to high memory consumption. It seems that the view models and views were being recreated but the old view models were kept in the background.

I also tried the official approach with `strings.xml` files for respective locales in `values` directory, but the language change was visible only either after `Recreate()` call or restarting the app.

### How it's now

Then I abandoned *the `Recreate()` approach* and instead tried to just *refresh* the Android views after language change. Unfortunately this had several problems involved:

- I had to replace MvxLang bindings with more general binding to update on property change i.e. `local:MvxBind="Text Language(TextSource, 'translated_term')"` (`MvxLang` is `OneTime` only)
- I had to call `RaiseAllPropertiesChanged()` in `BaseViewModel`
- still only the current Activity was being updated and e.g. tab bar and other activities and fragments remained in previous language

Now only restarting the app allows to use the app in different language.

### What I would like to have

I'd like to be able to update Android views without restarting the app or I would like to use `Recreate()` call without flooding the memory (i.e. either disposing the old views and view models or reusing them). Is there any proper way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is call `RaiseAllPropertiesChanged` on all ViewModels that are still alive. Here is one way to do this:

Create a message that will be broadcast when ChangeLocally in invoked in your AppLanguageService:

```
public class CultureChangedMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; private set; }

    public CultureChangedMessage(object sender, CultureInfo cultureInfo) : base(sender)
    {
        CultureInfo = cultureInfo;
    }
}
```

Subscribe to this message in BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _cultureChangedToken;

    public BaseViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        _cultureChangedToken = messenger.Subscribe<CultureChangedMessage>(OnCultureChanged);
    }

    private async void OnCultureChanged(CultureChangedMessage cultureChangedMessage)
    {
        await RaiseAllPropertiesChanged();
    }
    ...
}
```

Publish the message each time the Culture is changed in AppLanguageService:

```
private void ChangeLocally(string code)
{
    Settings.ApplicationLanguage = code;
    Strings.Culture = new CultureInfo(code);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Strings.Culture;
    ((MvxResxTextProvider) textProvider).CurrentLanguage = Strings.Culture;

    //let all ViewModels that are active know the culture changed
    Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish<CultureChangedMessage>(new CultureChangedMessage(new CultureInfo(code)));
}
```